# How to make a margin between the fields in a bootstrap 4 form row which spans in 2 rows on sm displays?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a bootstrap 4 form with some fields that should be in one row for screens larger than sm, and to put them in 2 rows otherwise.

I tried to do that using this code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
  </div>
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-form-label">Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

For **md**+, the fields will be in one row: 2+6+2+2
For **sm**, the row will be 2+10 (let's name that *A*), and the next one - *B* -  2+4...

My problem is that between the new 'rows' *A* and *B* there is no margin, like it would be if we would had 2 divs with the "row" class.

See in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/truesoft/q1djhp5b/ there is Row 1 just for example of the margin, it has a margin between the next one. But there is no margin when the Type `label` and `select` go on the next line when the screen is **sm**. I tried to make a margin for the submit button, but if I put to those ones, it will not be displayed ok in the other case.

[image: The margins are marked with red]

Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. You just need to add in the correct combination of  [spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row py-sm-3 mb-0">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Row 1:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row pb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="file">File:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control mb-sm-3" id="file" type="text">
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-form-label" for="type">Type</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 mb-3">
      <select class="form-control" id="type">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-sm-1 offset-md-8 col-sm-4">
      <input name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I also took the liberty to make the `type` field a tad bigger on `md`, as it seemed a bit too squeezed and I had where to take space from. Of course, that's totally optional, it will work if you revert them back.

What your example was missing were the `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` classes.

Comment: Just what I needed! I see that you added also a div for the submit button that wasn't aligned properly.